# How can I synchronize all PDFs from one directory with Dropbox?

Tags: find, rsync, dropbox, ln

I want to synchronize all the PDFs from one directory (my Zotero library) to Dropbox. Finally, I want to have a list of all the PDFs, not the directory names.

I successfully synchronized all my PDFs with the following command:

```
rsync -az --include="*/" --include="*.pdf" --exclude="*" \ 
--prune-empty-dirs /zotero /dropbox
```

I think I can easily set up a `cron` job to redo that task every day, but haven't tried that yet.

But now my folder on Dropbox still has all the directories with the PDFs in it (e.g. `6NVTACJH > xyz.pdf`)

**My problem:**
I would love to only have all the pdfs listed in one directory. Following an [advice](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/153112-rsync-multiple-directories-into-single-directory-remote.html) from the web, I tried to `find` all pdfs and create a hardlink.

But this command does not work yet.

```
ln $( find -name="*.pdf" -type f - links 1 ) /dropbox
```

Can you please help me with that last command?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using find -exec rather than command substitution cos it handles filenames well.

If you are trying to copy all pdf files into one single level /dropbox dir?

```
find /zotero -type f -name '*.pdf' -exec cp {} /dropbox/ \;
```

If you want links:

```
find /zotero -type f -name '*.pdf' -exec ln {} /dropbox/ \;
```

Update:
    You can use rsync on single file, just replace cp/ln with rsync(This will be slow):

```
find /zotero -type f -name '*.pdf' -exec rsync -avz {} /dropbox/ \;
```

Another choice is tar, which also provide updating by access time function.

I have to ask why you need to do this, you use Dropbox's limited version control? Or are you using Dropbox to share the files on-the-fly?

For those I need versioning and alpha-updating I personally have git or bazaar repository resides in Dropbox folder, do commit in my local dir, then push to Dropbox folder, simply faster than any hoster.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The only problem I see is that I constantly add new items to Zotero, so I have to rerun the script. But if I try to copy ALL PDFs again, there might be a problem for a cron job, right, because I would need to override existing file. What do you think about that?

Comment: As update, you can rsync a single file one by one